# Rails app fails to work after Node Upgrade

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails App that was working until recently. I wanted to see about moving from Rails 5 to Rails 6 and upgrading from Ruby 2.7 to Ruby 3. I'm running on a windows machine. After the upgrades and installs my Rails app no longer works. FWIW, I verified it works on another machine, so it's not Rails per se.

When I run the app in development, I'm getting the following error:

`Your nodejs binary failed to load autoprefixer script file, please check if you're running a supported version (10, 12, 14+)`

It seems to be triggered by this line

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

I've verified my node version.

```
node -v
v14.18.0
```

I've tried downgrading Node, upgrading Node, etc... and I can't figure out what is wrong.

I reversed the order of the javascript_include_tag and stylesheet_link_tag, so that it looks like this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Now when I run, I get an error that says

```
["ok"]

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

(execjs):1

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__540433433_88520700'
```

Has anyone else run into this and have any idea how to resolve?

Comment: Have you tried running `bundle update autoprefixer`?

Comment: @mutantkeyboard - I tried that and ```bundle update autoprefixer-rails``` and no change.

Answer (score 2):

I FIGURED IT OUT!!!!!

Background:
I had been receiving this message "`The system cannot find the path specified.`" every time I launched a command prompt.  I had also seen it in the logs, but since the command prompt window loaded fine, I thought it was a red herring and something to deal with another day.

After digging and digging I finally decided to tackle this issue because it too was bugging me and I needed a distraction.

Short history.  I had installed CMDER from https://cmder.net/.  In my efforts to configure it, I fubar'd something so I uninstalled it.  Then I reinstalled it - but then realized I installed it at a place I didn't want it.  So, uninstall, reinstall again.  At one point I installed it under a folder `cmdr` vs `cmder`.  In one of my attempts, I edited the registry without a registry backup.  Didn't seem like a big deal at the time.  [Borrowing](https://javahungry.blogspot.com/2021/07/the-system-can-not-find-the-path-specified-error-in-command-prompt.html) from a related error message blog, I opened my registry to

`HKEY\_CURRENT\_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Command Processor\\AutoRun` and found that it pointed to a file location that was misspelled (remember the cmder vs cmdr above).

Once I fixed that, everything works again.  I have no idea why there was an error with Rails with this, but there was.

Comment: Had the same issue here, mine was related to conda which I've had uninstalled previously. Thanks alot.